# Repopulate select2 with data without losing selected index

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2-4

I have many `select2` items on my page, which is all filled with items.

I add new data from a modal, and after modal closes I repopulate all `select2` with the new data. I found that the `select2` loses the selected value !!

This is the code I use:

```
 $.get(callPath, { }, function(dataDropDown) {

            $('.'+ refInput).each(function(){                                          
                    $(this).html(dataDropDown);
                    $(this).trigger("change");
            });

           // $("'" + refInput + "'").html(dataDropDown);
        })
```

I want to repopulate the elements without losing the selected value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.get(callPath, { }, function(dataDropDown) {

      $('.'+ refInput).each(function(){  
           // get current value:  
           var selected = $(this).select2('val');                     
                $(this).html(dataDropDown);
                $(this).trigger("change");
           // set it after repopulate:
           $(this).select2('val', selected);
     });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the selected value in your Ajax request function. Something like this:

```
var selectedId = $('#myselect').val();
$.get(callPath, { }, function(dataDropDown, selectedId) {

        $('.'+ refInput).each(function(){                                          
                $(this).html(dataDropDown);
                $(this).trigger("change");
        });
        $('#myselect').val(selectedId);

       // $("'" + refInput + "'").html(dataDropDown);
    })
```

Comment: in my case there is multiple select2 items so how i can return all of them back

Comment: Actually the snippet I've provided should also work in that case. You have to get the selected values in array and then use in to re-select the values after AJAX call. Something like this:
`$("#myselect").val(["1", "2"]);`